# Syntax error help -Python 3 on IDLE

Tags: python, syntax

```
multiNum = 1.0
multiDen = 1.0
for den in range(11,100):
    for num in range(10,den): # ensure fraction < 1
        if (den%10 != 0 or  num%10 != 0):
            frac = num/den
            cancelFrac = (float(str(num)[0])) / (float(str(den)[0])         
            if ((abs(frac - cancelFrac)) < 0.00001):
                multiNum = multiNum*(int(str(num)[0]))
                multiDen = multiDen*(int(str(den)[0]))
## simplyfy fraction
i = 2
while ((multiNum%i == 0) and (multiDen%i == 0)):
    multiNum = multiNum/i
    multiDen = multiDen/i                                          
i = 3
while ((multiNum%i == 0) and (multiDen%i == 0)):
    multiNum = multiNum/i
    multiDen = multiDen/i
i = 5
inc = 2
while (i < 82):    ## this function generates primes (and more)
    while ((multiNum%i == 0) and (multiDen%i == 0)):
        multiNum = multiNum/i
        multiDen = multiDen/i 
    i = i + inc
    inc=6-inc
print(multiDen)
```

This program is being used for project euler problem 33, I cant find the syntax error.  I am using IDLE.
Here is the problem I am trying to solve

The fraction 49/98 is a curious fraction, as an inexperienced mathematician in attempting to simplify it may incorrectly believe that 49/98 = 4/8, which is correct, is obtained by cancelling the 9s.

We shall consider fractions like, 30/50 = 3/5, to be trivial examples.

There are exactly four non-trivial examples of this type of fraction, less than one in value, and containing two digits in the numerator and denominator.

If the product of these four fractions is given in its lowest common terms, find the value of the denominator.

Comment: You should atleast indicate which line the error was thrown from.

Comment: You need to add the traceback to your main post, there's no way for us to help without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using way too many parentheses in your code when the grouping would be handled by the order of operations. For example, `while ((multiNum%i == 0) and (multiDen%i == 0)):` could just be `while multiNum%i == 0 and multiDen%i == 0:`, or `while not (multiNum%i or multiDen%i):` with De Morgan's Law.

This parenthetical profusion has led to missing one on line 7:

```
cancelFrac = (float(str(num)[0])) / (float(str(den)[0])
                                                       ^
```

I recommend using a development environment that keeps track of matching brackets. Even something like Notepad++ would do.

Answer (score 1):

One syntax error that I can see is this:

```
cancelFrac = (float(str(num)[0])) / (float(str(den)[0])  
#Mismatched parenthesis right here  ^------------------^
```

You also have too many parenthesis in general. For example, this would work just fine:

```
cancelFrac = float(str(num)[0]) / float(str(den)[0])
```

And this

```
i = 2
while ((multiNum%i == 0) and (multiDen%i == 0)):
    multiNum = multiNum/i
    multiDen = multiDen/i
```

should be simplified to this

```
i = 2
while multiNum % i == 0 and multiDen % i == 0:
    multiNum = multiNum/i
    multiDen = multiDen/i
```

Also, in the future, please include your traceback, it will help everyone help you find the error.